# Invite Links with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I want to build an invite system where each registered user has a unique invite link. And when their friends use that link to sign up they both get benefits. You should also be able to send the link through social media or email.

An example of what I mean is airbnb's invite system:

[image]

I have tried using devise invitable but it seems to work differently. It seems to register an user with an email first and then signs them up if they accept the invite. This does not allow for social media sharing.

So, how do I go about building such an invite system and how do I integrate it with devise.

Comment: Maybe you should look into this https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Comment: @ak1712 I tried using devise inevitable but it works differently from what I intended. It seems to register a user with an email first, which does not allow for social media sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create specific route for this links, like eg `/r/1234` (where `1234`) is referrer code assigned to Referrer.

Once referee go through this link in assigned to this route controller you set the cookie `referrer=1234` and redirect to signup page.

Let's add to `User` model :referrer_code_on_signup attribute:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :referrer_code_on_signup
  after_commit :grand_rewards, on: create
  # ... other user stuff

  private

    def grand_rewards
      return unless referrer_code_on_signup.present?

      # some rewards logic
    end
end
```

In case if referee will pass signup form and submit it you should tweak registrations controller:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    if cookies[:referrer].present?
      build_resource(referrer_code_on_signup: cookies[:referrer])
    else
      build_resource
    end
  end
end
```

And then tell devise to use that controller instead of the default with:

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

For the special route:
You could create ReferrerController:

```
# app/controllers/referrers_controller.rb
class ReferrersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_referrer

  # Endpoint for share referrer link like example.com/r/123456 - redirects to
  # sign in page and setup referrer cookies
  def show
    cookies[:referrer] = @referrer.referrer_code if @referrer.present?
    redirect_to user_sign_up_path
  end

  private

    def set_referrer
      @referrer = User.find_by(referrer_code: params[:id])
    end
end
```

And update your routes with line:

```
resources :referrers, only: :show, path: :r
```

We assume your `User` model has `referrer_code` stored at DB and assigns random, unique value on signup

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Im not sure how to create a specific route like you said. Do I need to build a referral model?

Comment: you could add one more attribute for User model, like referrer code and at before create set the value. So all users will have own referrer codes.

Comment: @Railsdeveloperbeginner2002 I updated my answer with specific route setup